# android volley json parser error

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

My problem is that my android app does not parse the following **JSON** data. If I use other **JSON** sources it parses OK. I've validated the **JSON** bellow and there were no problems. It doesn't throw any error. I can't understand why.

**JSON data looks like this:**

```
    [
{
"Id":"1",
"name":"habib",
"f":[
{
"Id":"1",
"taeed":"0",
"codkala":"101",
"namekala":"سس گوجه فرنگی",
"count":"5",
"chid":"0"
},
{
"Id":"1",
"taeed":"0",
"codkala":"102",
"namekala":"ماست موسیر",
"count":"1",
"chid":"0"
},
{
"Id":"1",
"taeed":"0",
"codkala":"103",
"namekala":"شیر گم چرب",
"count":"3",
"chid":"0"
}
]
},
{
"Id":"2",
"name":"habib",
"f":[
{
"Id":"2",
"taeed":"0",
"codkala":"101",
"namekala":"سس گوجه فرنگی",
"count":"5",
"chid":"0"
},
{
"Id":"2",
"taeed":"0",
"codkala":"102",
"namekala":"ماست موسیر",
"count":"1",
"chid":"0"
},
{
"Id":"2",
"taeed":"0",
"codkala":"103",
"namekala":"شیر گم چرب",
"count":"3",
"chid":"0"
}
]
}
]
```

And my code for parsing:

```
public class AnbarParser {
public static List<AnbarModel> parseFeedAnbar(String content){
    try {

        JSONArray ar = new JSONArray(content);
        List<AnbarModel> anbarModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i<1; i++){
            JSONObject obj = ar.getJSONObject(i);

            AnbarModel anbarModel = new AnbarModel();
            anbarModel.setId(obj.getString("Id"));
            anbarModel.setName(obj.getString("name"));

            List<Faktor> faktorlist = new ArrayList<>();

            JSONArray arr2 = obj.getJSONArray("f");
            for (int ii = 0; i<1; ii++){
                JSONObject obj2 = arr2.getJSONObject(i);
                Faktor faktor = new Faktor();
                faktor.setId(obj2.getString("Id"));
                faktor.setTaeed(obj2.getString("taeed"));
                faktor.setCodkala(obj2.getString("codkala"));
                faktor.setNamekala(obj2.getString("namekala"));
                faktor.setCount(obj2.getString("count"));
                faktor.setChid(obj2.getString("chid"));
                faktorlist.add(faktor);
            }
            anbarModel.setFaktor(faktorlist);
            anbarModelList.add(anbarModel);



        }

        return anbarModelList;



    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
    //return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Move the return statement after the catch, and the creation of theanbarModelList as the first row in the method. before the try statement.

Comment: check your for condition you have initialized ii check condition for i. check your for loop closely.

Comment: did my answer helped you??

Comment: Thank you for the help you .
Yes, it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you missed a small "`i`" in you array for loop.

Since i is greater than 1 because of its previous loop, it will never come inside the for loop for array. change your code link below.

check the below code.

```
for (int ii = 0; ii<1; ii++){ // here is the only change. add ii instead of i
            JSONObject obj2 = arr2.getJSONObject(ii); // here also replace your i with ii
            Faktor faktor = new Faktor();
            faktor.setId(obj2.getString("Id"));
            faktor.setTaeed(obj2.getString("taeed"));
            faktor.setCodkala(obj2.getString("codkala"));
            faktor.setNamekala(obj2.getString("namekala"));
            faktor.setCount(obj2.getString("count"));
            faktor.setChid(obj2.getString("chid"));
            faktorlist.add(faktor);
        }
```

Comment: kindly accept it as correct answer if it helps you.